# Trying to use a for loop to cycle through repeating timers in swift

Tags: swift, loops, timer

I have 2 timers setup one at 20 seconds the other at 60 I need to repeat these in a loop 6 times, such as 20 then 60 and repeat but cannot seem to do so. Every time I place them in the loop the timer accelerates. It should call timer1() then timer2() and repeat but I'm not sure why its not.

```
 for _ in 1...6 {
        timer1()
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 19 
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            self.timer2()
            }
        }

func timer1() {
    beginnerStart()
    beginnerTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.beginnerStart), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

 @objc func beginnerStart() {
    warmUpCountDown = warmUpCountDown - 1
    if warmUpCountDown == 0 {
        beginnerTimer.invalidate()
    }
```

Comment: You are using 19 instead of 20 when dispatching after, why?

Comment: Also note that the `for` you are writing will cause `timer2()` calls to appear quite close together as they are scheduled one after the other

Comment: The 19 is to remove the delay when the timer switches from the 20 second timer to the 60 I tried 20 at first but it caused a noticeable delay, and the for loop is the issue I need these timers too repeat 6 times but I need the loop to wait on each set to complete and I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: if you post the contents of timer1() and timer2() functions, we can probably answer it.

Comment: Also, is it part of your homework assignment that they HAVE to be in a loop?

Comment: I added timer1 and the function it calls, it's not for an assignment it's an app I am trying to get working, if there is a way to do it without the loop thats fine I just need a label to countdown from 1 value and switch to the other timer value after it reaches 0 and be able to repeat the process.

Comment: Oh and timer2 is exactly the same as timer1 just different variable for count down time.